# How to route an img src to a controller action upon click

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have an image in my navbar, that when I click, I want it to route to the Index action, my home page.

I see peoples solution of putting `Url.ActionFor` in there `src =""` but with that solution, there is no where to put my image.

What would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your image in an  tag that links to your Action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MyController")"><img src="url_of_navbar_image"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not decorate your image with  tags?

```
<a href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controller name")"><img src="../../Content/Images/Image.bmp", alt="Alt" /></a>
```

Don't know why you would want to insert this into a `src` attr.

Answer (score 0):

in your view :

```
<a class="my-auto" asp-controller="ControlerName" asp-action="ActionName">
    <img src="/path/to/image" alt="logo" class="logo">
</a>
```